# Listview with multiple item columns for tablet?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am currently trying to create a tablet optimized version of my app. However, difficulties occur when i try to populate the screen with a listview that consist of THREE item columns.
Heres a brief illustration:
[image]

What is the best way to do this?

**UPDATE**
The problem is dont know how to setup a listview with 3 columns. In my phone version app, i use a simple listview where each item when clicked opens another activity. How to achieve such for 3 columns?

Comment: Ok. What is the issue you are having? More description and related code will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think [Grid view](http://android-helper.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-simple-gridview-example.html) can be used in your case. Even it is a custom view you can still inflate layout and apply it for single item.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LayoutInflater and inflate a sublayout from xml to create a multicolumn listview. Have a look at [Multi Column ListView](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/) and [this](http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/multicolumn-listview-with-image-icon/)

Comment: Thanks but that wasnt quite what i was looking for :s I think gridview might do.